# Suddenly reboot

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-moto-g, lineageos

I am still using an old Moto G (2013)
It works quite well. 
But sometimes it starts to behave as if a Power button is pressed - Power button menu appears, and then reboot is started, without any activity of mine)
I supposed, there is something about a mechanics in power button.
But, when I press the  button of charging phone it just splashes showing it is charging without a sign the button is working wrong.
The question :
Is it hardware or software problem?
If software, then could you guide me to file, where i can find log of booting
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Sudden reboots of old devices often indicate a dying battery (voltage goes down for some milliseconds). How often does these reboots occur? Do they still occur if you are connected to a charger?

Comment: Robert, thank you for comment. Reboot occurs couple three of four times a day. Each time it is not a single reboot: system starts booting, then it reboots again while there is os logo on screen. And there can be couple reboots more until home screen appears. Reboot can occur even if device is connected to charger.